# Date Format in Oracle PlSql

Tags: sql, oracle, date-arithmetic

This is existing code,can anyone explain it?

```
  var_l_year_days := to_number(to_char(to_date(to_char(to_date
 (ADD_MONTHS(var_l_mnth_details(i) .var_l_mnth_start_date, 12),
'DD-MM-YYYY'),'YYYY') ||'1231','YYYYMMDD'),'DDD'));
```

Answer (score 1):

> to_date
>    (ADD_MONTHS(var_l_mnth_details(i) .var_l_mnth_start_date, 12),
>   'DD-MM-YYYY')

This is a bug in your code. Never apply **TO_DATE** on a **DATE**. It forces Oracle to:

- first convert it into a string
- then convert it back to date

based on the **locale-specific NLS settings**. You need TO_DATE to convert a literal into date. For **date-arithmetic**, leave the date as it is.

Use:

- `TO_CHAR` - to display the date in your desired format
- `TO_DATE` - to convert a literal into date.

You could simplify the query in the following way:

```
SQL> SELECT add_months(TRUNC(SYSDATE,'year'), 24)
  2       - add_months(TRUNC(SYSDATE,'year'), 12) days_in_next_year
  3  FROM dual;

DAYS_IN_NEXT_YEAR
-----------------
              366
```

Comment: @Abc16 You are welcome. Please mark it as answered, would help others too!

Answer (score 0):

To me it seems returning number of days in year next to `var_l_mnth_details(i).var_l_mnth_start_date`. Basically finding out if next year is the leap year or not.

Alhough this can be simplified into:

```
var_l_year_days := TO_NUMBER(TO_CHAR(TRUNC(ADD_MONTHS(var_l_mnth_details(i).var_l_mnth_start_date, 24), 'YEAR') - 1, 'DDD'));
```